# Loading a CSV file with inconsistent spaces after commas

Tags: mysql, sql, database, csv

I want to load a CSV file using `LOAD DATA INFILE` command, but the spaces after the commas are inconsistent i.e. there are commas which are followed by a space and commas that aren't.

I tried using `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","` directive, but some of the fields in the resulting table contained a leading space; If the input was

```
abc,def, ghi, klm
```

then after the loading my table had

```
column1 = 'abc'
column2 = 'def'
column3 = ' ghi'
column4 = ' klm'
```

Note that columns 3 and 4 contain a leading space.

I want my columns to not contain leading spaces. How should I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would this work?

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv'
INTO TABLE t1 (column1, @col2, @col3, @col4)
SET
  column2 = TRIM(@col2),
  column3 = TRIM(@col3),
  column4 = TRIM(@col4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a short `sed` replace pattern to do it:

```
sed -i 's/, /,/g' file.csv
```

After that, file.csv (its content was "abc,def, ghi, klm") contains:

```
abc,def,ghi,klm
```