# Function failing to update spacing after comma

Tags: python, csv, with-statement, readlines, writelines

I have a csv file that has inconsistent spacing after the comma, like this:

`534323, 93495443,34234234, 3523423423, 2342342,236555, 6564354344`

I have written a function that tries to read in the file and makes the spacing consistent, but it doesn't appear to update anything. After opening the new file created, there is no difference from the original. The function I've written is:

```
def ensure_consistent_spacing_in_csv(dirpath, original_name, new_name):
    with open(dirpath + original_name, "r") as f:
        data = f.readlines()
    for item in data:
        if "," in data:
            comma_index = item.index(",")
            if item[comma_index + 1] != " ":
                item = item.replace(",", ", ")
    with open(dirpath + new_name, "w") as f:
        f.writelines(data)
```

Where am I going wrong?

I have looked at the answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630170/python-parse-csv-file-replace-commas-with-colons), but I cannot use that method as I need the delimiter to be ", ", which is two characters and hence not allowed. I also tried to follow the method in the `sed` answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280052/loading-a-csv-file-with-inconsistent-spaces-after-commas) using a `process.call` system, but that also failed and I don't know bash well so I'm hesitant to go that route and would like to use a pure python method.

Thank you!

Comment: Hello, how about you split the whole file by comma and then use strip() method to get rid of remaining whitespaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original code has a couple bugs:

- The `if "," in data` condition never evaluates to true. `data` is a list, where each item in the list is a string representing one entire line of the file. No single line in the file is `,`, so that condition never evaluates to true. To fix it, use `if "," in item`. That way it's checking to see if each line has a comma.
- There's also a second problem: the `item.index` function returns only the first instance of a comma, so if there's inconsistent spacing twice in one the algorithm does not catch it.

A simple solution that doesn't require regular expressions or `sed` or indexing and looking at each word character by character is:

```
with open(dirpath + orig_filename, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        new_line = line.replace(" ", "").replace(",", ", ")
        with open(dirpath + cleaned_filename, "a") as cleaned_data:
            cleaned_data.writelines(new_line)
```

What this is doing is:

1. `for line in f` reads each line of the file.
2. `line.replace(" ", "").replace(",", ", "))` first removes all spaces entirely (thanks to @megakarg for the suggestion) from the line, and then makes sure there's a single space after each comma to meet the spec.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I was able to normalize the spacing given a string from your example

**NOTE**: I am assuming the content of the file isn't large enough to exceed the available memory since you read it into the list in your code.

**NOTE**: using regular expressions may not always (read almost never) be he most efficient way to solve a problem, but it gets the job done.

```
regex = r"(?<=\d)\s*,\s*(?=\d)" # please see the UPD:
test_str = "534323, 93495443,34234234, 3523423423, 2342342,236555, 6564354344"
subst = ", "
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)
print(result)
```

will produce

```
534323, 93495443, 34234234, 3523423423, 2342342, 236555, 6564354344
```

and for the file with the following context:

```
1,    2, 3, 4,5,6
1,2,3,4,  5,    6
1,        2,3,4,5,6
```

I ran

```
with open('test.csv') as f:
    data = f.read()
regex = r"(?<=\d)\s*,\s*(?=\d)" # please see the UPD:
subst = ", "
result = re.sub(regex, subst, data)
print(result)
```

and got this result:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

**Alternatively** you could use the csv module to read the rows and for each row you would strip() the element.

**UPD:**
The regex could be simplified to

```
regex = r"\s*,\s*"
```